# Probability - Bag containing balls

Tags: probability

5 balls are drawn from a bag containing 6 white balls and 4 black balls.  What is the probability that at least three of of the 5 balls are white?

I am having difficulty with this question.  I like Probabliity but this question has confused me as I am unsure of how to approach it.  Perhaps it's a very easy question but as of now I am stuck.

The only attempt I made was thnking the question had to do with combinations or am I wrong?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to look at a hypergeometric distribution here. To get exactly three white balls, you take:

$$
P(X = 3) = \frac{ \binom{6}{3} \binom{4}{2} }{ \binom{10}{5} }
$$

So we choose three white balls, which is given by $\binom{6}{3}$. This is independent of the number of ways to choose $2$ black balls. We divide this by the number of ways to choose $5$ balls out of $10$.

Now how do you get $4$ black balls and $1$ white ball? How about $5$ white balls? How would you modify the hypergeometric count for each of these items. Note that each outcome is independent of the previous, so you add them up.